# creating multiple instances of windows phone 7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7-emulator

Is it possible to create multiple instances of windows phone 7 emulator (need not be done simultaneously) ?
I am designing an android app which acts as the client and will be used by multiple users (not simultaneously) and in the server side I have a windows console application in C#. I want to launch windows phone 7 emulator instance corresponding to each user.

Also, each time I launch the emulator, only Internet Explorer is present. The apps which I deployed previously using Application Deployment are not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link may just be enough to solve your problem.

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/how-run-multiple-instances

Comment: Thanks for your support. It solved my problem of creating multiple instances. But still, apps deployed previously using app deployment are missing when I open the emulator next time. Any suggestions on that ?